# Finding algorithm with Binwalk

Tags: algorithm, firmware, reversing, ghidra, binwalk

actually, it all started when I wanted to update the map of my car navigation.
The map of the device can only be updated with the sd card and unfortunately it does not update because the cid code on the sd card does not match. I wanted to find the algorithm that calculates this in the firmware of the device, so I discovered binwalk.
I know x86 assembler and python at a very basic level and binwalk is out of my league. I tried to do something with binwalk below, but I have no idea where to start. I would be very grateful if you could help me (sorry for my English).

`code`
https://pastebin.com/BDKrxwNX

I analysed the firmware with Binwalk, I searched for text such as error message that can match the cid code with Ghidra, but I couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Your question may get more audience on https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

How can I at least view the ".c files" contained in the extracted 106378A file content? Maybe I can find something useful in these files:

3.24.74/CK505X_AT/Soft/Build/../../../Blues32/Soft/Sources//Common/Messaging/BLM_SMS.c
4175160       0x3FB538        Unix path: /home/ck5050/Version-3.24.74/CK505X_AT/Soft/Build/../../../Blues32/Soft/Sources//SyncML/opaque.c
4178484       0x3FC234        Unix path: /home/ck5050/Version-3.24.74/CK505X_AT/Soft/Build/../../../CommonSoft/Crypto/aes.c
4182704       0x3FD2B0        AES Inverse S-Box
4187104       0x3FE3E0        Unix path: /home/ck5050/Version-3.24.74/CK505X_AT/Soft/Build/../../../CommonSoft/Crypto/md5.c
4207752       0x403488        Unix path: /home/ck5050/Version-3.24.74/CK505X_AT/Soft/Build/../../../Tango/Soft/Sources/celp/celp_interface.c
4211128       0x4041B8        Unix path: /home/ck5050/Version-

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).